# Propagating enter in custom Angular input

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a custom Angular input component that using a `textarea` as it's input field.

How do I propagate the enter key event to the parent form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom event which will be send to the parent once your enter key event is received.

**In your custom input element :**

```
@Output() onEnterPressed:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();


// Method called on KeyUp event. Using KeyUp as it recommended by Angular for Keyboard events.
handleKeyPressed(keyEvent:KeyboardEvent) {
   
  if(enter_key_is_pressed) {
    this.onEnterPressed.emit(keyEvent);
  }
}
```

**In parent component template:**

```
<custom-input [onEnterPressed]="handleEnterEvent($event)"></custom-input>
```

**In parent component component class:**

```
handleEnterEvent(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
  //do_whatever_you_want
}
```

Comment: there is a typo, it is EventEmitter not EventEmmitter

Answer (score 0):

Almost all events (including keyup events) bubble up to the parent elements by default.

#### Example

```
<form (keyup.enter)="addAction('form')">
  <textarea (keyup.enter)="addAction('textarea')"></textarea>
  <input-component (keyup.enter)="addAction('input')"></input-component>
</form>
```

For both the textarea as the component, the enter event will bubble up to the form.

Try it out with this [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/GNgenuLOrUyoUoue5OaL/).